# Exception occurred during order load - Sales => Orders

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, sales-order, magento2.4

**Error under Sales => Orders: Exception occurred during order load**

Kindly tell me, why this error is coming ? How to I can fix this issue ? I am using Magento 2.4.0.

[image]

Comment: exception throw from `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/View.php` file. there must be a log entry for above exception. please check at `var/log/exception.log

Comment: @Pawan - There this error is showing
Invalid block type: Aalogics\Tcs\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View 
{"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0):

Comment: it seems it is a custom module and having some issue with code. you can disable module and can confirm.please check corresponding block exist for phtml OR you need to debug code line by line!